# XMMP Server Setup

Tags: xmpp, chat

I have to utilize live chat capabilities using XMPP with existing users and their messages (SQL Tables)

What is the best way port all users and their message onto XMPP server ?

Can I connect my existing users and messages to XMPP server ?

What are alternatives for implementing live chat on existing data (users and messages ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can follow:

1) Deploy your own XMPP server, for example:

- [ejabberd](https://www.ejabberd.im/)
- [Openfire](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/)
- [Tigase](https://tigase.net/)

There are many others as well

The main drawback here is that you need to deploy, pay hosting fee, monitor, keep up-time of the server by yourself which is not optimal.

2) Use ready to go Cloud Messaging platforms. 
There are also many example in the wild, e.g Twillio, ConnectyCube, Layer etc.

I can give you an example: in some of my mobile & web projects I used [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/) Messaging and Video calling cloud back-end which [provides](https://connectycube.com/features/) messaging capabilities, user base, push notifications, video calling, chat bots.

So with such platforms you do no care about server hosting, server monitor, server up-time and others server related stuff, you just you the APIs you need in your app. Mostly such platforms provide FREE plans along with dedicated Enterprise solutions where you own your data (it is deployed on your own AWS account for example). So highly recommended.

Regarding migration of your users - if you decided to deploy own XMPP server (point #1) then you need to learn their doc and understand their DB structure, so then you write a migration script.

If you decided to use cloud messaging platforms (point #2) then you can contact their support and ask them to do Users import, so you need to provide them some json/csv files with your users.